# How much can we scale the data in Neo4j

Tags: performance, neo4j, bigdata, scalability, graph-databases

I have 5 million products and 100 000 sellers as data in Neo4j database.The sellers have some common products among all the products portfolio. These products and sellers are the nodes and the relationships between them are edges in the **Neo4j** database. How to scale the **Neo4j** database. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: There is (in pratical) no limitation in terms of numbers of node & relationship, so you store all your data into Neo4j.  SO what do you mean by scale ? In read, write, storage, ... ? If you want to have an idea about the sizing, I recommand you this https://neo4j.com/hardware-sizing-calculator

Comment: @logisima, scale in terms of storage, complexity, query performance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just some millions of nodes (and generally the double in term of relationships), the size of your database will be less than 10Gb ...

So about the storage, everything fits on a server (even on a USB key ^^).

For the rest of your question (complexity & query performance) it depends a lot of what kind of queries you want to do, so it's an **opened question** ...

The only thing I can tell you without more information, is that the performance of queries is not dependent of the size of your graph.

Cheers.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on that last sentence where you say "is that the performance of queries is not dependent of the size of your graph" - I assume you mean that with the assumption that the graph fits in memory. Correct?

Comment: A native graph database has a local approach (vs ensemblist approach in rdbms) : you start from one node, and then you traverse relationships. So the performance of a query depends on what you traverse, not on the size of your DB.